# scalablelist index outside the allowed range

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

While previewing and trying to export a report to PDF in Visual Studio 2010, gives the following error :

an error occured during local report processing
an error occured during rendering of the report
ScalableList: Index 8 outside the allowed range[0::7]

When i generate a report for a lesser duration it seems to work. The only solution I could find on the internet is removing HideDuplicates and installing hotfixes which doesnt work. Can somebody please give me more information about HideDuplicates and what exactly to do?

Is there any other solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, simply removing additional formatting that I had put in for branding(the company logo etc.) did the job. I am not sure of why this happened but this is a solution I came to through trial and error. Also try not to leave any blank space at the top of the report that is to be exported - i.e keep it edge to edge with the page boundary.

Answer (score 3):

Scenario:
SSRS Tablix with grouping and page breaks contains hidden column. While preview worked fine, export to PDF caused that error. The index points, in my case, to the first column which causes error. Once I made column visible, error message pointed  index to the next hidden column.

Solution:
While installing hotfix was not an option, I removed hide option from the COLUMN properties, and applied it to an each individual tablix CELL property for header and detail row. 
Not miraculously for Microsoft it worked for me. Long live Microsoft...

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didn't have any "Hide Duplicates". Visual Studio 2015 SSRS report.
I went through my hidden columns and one of the columns that wasn't even on the end was triggering this area when it was set to "Hide" and not "Show" in TextBox properties. So I set it to "Show" and just shrank the column down to almost nothing. Also set the border to none and report worked and was visibly good.